# Capturar Login de Usuario y Usarlo en toda la Aplicacion

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

Estoy desarrollando una aplicación en `ASP.NET MVC 5` y al iniciar la aplicación capturo el usuario de `Windows` en mi controlador `Index`.

```
string login = User.Identity.Name.ToString()
```

¿Cómo puedo hacer para tener disponible este valor (variable `login`) en todos los controladores de mi aplicación, ya que en la mayoría de la aplicación necesito hacer consulta o cálculos con este dato?

Actualmente tengo que ir controlador por controlador capturando este valor, pero tendría que haber una forma de capturar el valor solo en el controlador `index` y poder usarlo en los demás controladores.

Comment: puede ser una propiedad  en un controlador base.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Puedes utilizar una variable de session

Cuando inicie tu aplicación has lo siguiente

```
Session["login"] = User.Identity.Name.ToString();
```

Luego en cualquier controlador puedes preguntar por esa variable de session

```
if (Session["login"]!=null)
{
//Si la session es valida puedes realizar alguna acción como 
//redireccionar al home
return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
}
else
{
//Si la variable es null lo mandas al login 
return RedirectToAction("Index", "Login");
}
```

Tambien puedes usar esa variable de session en la vista sin problemas

```
@if(Session["login"] != null) //El @if es para que lo reconozca razor en la vista
{
 <a href="@Url.Action("Index","Home")">Inicio</a>
}
else
{
<a href="@Url.Action("Index","Login")">Ingresar</a>
}
```

Answer (score 0):

El hecho de utilizar variables de sesión, es una alternativa, pero yo en tu caso usaría **Cookies**.

Utilizar variables de sesión podría darte problemas a la hora de publicar tu aplicación ASP.NET MVC en un **entorno de producción**. 
Normalmente los proveedores de servicios de hosting funcionan con **granjas de servidores** web (Web farm) que implementan **balanceo de carga** para maximizar el rendimiento de las peticiones http y minimizar la carga de trabajo. 
Esto puede puede causar la **pérdida** de las variables de sesión, si son diferentes servidores los que atienden las peticiones a tu aplicación Web.

Por esta razón yo usaría **Cookies**, y en tu caso sería algo así.
**Creas** una nueva Cookie y la **envías** al navegador del usuario:

```
HttpCookie cookie = new HttpCookie("_NombreCookie", User.Identity.Name.ToString());
HttpContext.Response.SetCookie(cookie);
```

Para **recuperar** la Cookie desde tu Controlador sería así:

```
string login = HttpContext.Request.Cookies["_NombreCookie"]?.Value ?? string.Empty;
```

Para más seguridad también puedes **encriptar** el valor de tus Cookies. Te recomiendo leas el artículo [Encriptar y desencriptar cookies en una aplicación ASP.NET MVC](http://www.rafaelacosta.net/Blog/2018/9/19/encriptar-y-desencriptar-cookies-en-una-aplicaci%C3%B3n-aspnet-mvc) donde podrás ver como establecer y leer Cookies en ASP.NET MVC.

Answer (score 0):

Otra opción puede ser usar el local storage del browser. Naturalemente tienes que llevar el dato al cliente de algún modo, y esto opera con javascript.

```
window.localstorage.setItem("login", "valor")
```

para guardar y posteriormente

```
window.localstorage.getItem("login")
```

para recuperar.

ve este link para mayores detalles de las opciones ASP.Net
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17485244/what-are-different-types-of-sessions-in-asp-net